# C# MAUI Debug / Release different result on Windows with CollectionVIew & Commands

Tags: c#, visual-studio, maui

My Goal is to pass CollectionView selected item handle to MainPageVM.CVItemButton() function. Under Debug the passed handle it's not NULL(and works correct), but under Release it's NULL.

The reason for designing the structure like this is to separate the CollectionViewItem from its use in any particular place, so that it can be set with a separate command. Of course, it is also possible to not use SelfHandle, but I do not know how to pass the item handle to command. If there is a better way to pass parameters, please let me know.

Runable Samples on Git: https://github.com/ss1969/MauiParamNullSample

This sample is tested under VS 2022, MAUI framework, with CommunityToolkit.Mvvm module.

THANKS!!!!!!

The main parts of codes are below:

1, MainPage.xaml: build collectionview, pass the item handle to SelfHandle.

```
            <CollectionView HorizontalOptions="Center"
                            ItemsLayout="VerticalGrid"
                            ItemsSource="{Binding CVItems}"
                            SelectionMode="None">
                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <local:CollectionViewItem HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                                  Button1Command="{Binding CVItemButtonCommand, Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:MainPageVM}}}"
                                                  SelfHandle="{Binding}"
                                                  BindingContext="{Binding}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            </CollectionView>
```

2, MainPageVM: create commands, data

```
public partial class MainPageVM : ObservableObject
{
    public MainPageVM()
    {
        CVItems = new()
        {
            new (){ Value = 1},
        };
    }

    [ObservableProperty] private ObservableCollection<CollectionViewItemModel> _CVItems;
    [ObservableProperty] private string _Result;

    [RelayCommand(CanExecute = nameof(CanCVItemButton))]
    private void CVItemButton(CollectionViewItemModel m)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine($"Parameter shouldn't be NULL, in Debug it's not NULL, but in Release it's NULL");
        Result = ($"CVItemButton() Paramter is NULL => {m == null}");
    }

    private bool CanCVItemButton(CollectionViewItemModel m)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine($"CanCVItemButton() received an NULL parameter => {m == null}");
        return true;
    }
}
```

3, CollectionViewItem class, build 2 BindableProperty, the command and the parameter.

```
public partial class CollectionViewItem : ContentView
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty Button1CommandProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Button1Command), typeof(ICommand), typeof(CollectionViewItem), null, BindingMode.OneWay);
    public ICommand Button1Command
    {
        get => (ICommand)GetValue(Button1CommandProperty);
        set => SetValue(Button1CommandProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty SelfHandleProperty =
    BindableProperty.Create(nameof(SelfHandle), typeof(CollectionViewItemModel), typeof(CollectionViewItem), null, BindingMode.TwoWay);
    public CollectionViewItemModel SelfHandle
    {
        get => (CollectionViewItemModel)GetValue(SelfHandleProperty);
        set => SetValue(SelfHandleProperty, value);
    }

    public CollectionViewItem()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

4, CollectionView.xaml , describe the command

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiApp1.CollectionViewItem"
             x:Name="root">
    <HorizontalStackLayout>
        <Button Text="Button"
                Command="{Binding Button1Command, Source={x:Reference root}}"
                CommandParameter="{Binding SelfHandle, Source={x:Reference root}}" />
    </HorizontalStackLayout>
</ContentView>
```

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT, if Release version fails, how could published version work? This seems impossible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix:
In

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiApp1.CollectionViewItem"
             x:Name="root">
    <HorizontalStackLayout>
        <Button Text="Button"
                Command="{Binding Button1Command, Source={x:Reference root}}"
                CommandParameter="{Binding SelfHandle, Source={x:Reference root}}" />
    </HorizontalStackLayout>
</ContentView>
```

Use **CommandParameter={Binding}** to directly get the handle of current object. Solution verified. **SelfHandle** can be removed.

Comment: I don’t understand this answer. You say SelfHandle can be removed, but your code still contains SelfHandle. Please explain. And also show how the code that, in question, *uses* SelfHandle, would change. What would it do instead?

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve I mean CommandParameter="{Binding SelfHandle, Source={x:Reference root}}" can be changed to CommandParameter={Binding}. I just pasted the original code to show where to modify.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve with CommandParameter={Binding}, the CVItemButton() method can get correct handle of button I pressed, both in Debug & Release mode.

Comment: *”I just pasted the original code to show where to modify.”* - It is clearer (and the convention here) to show the *final* code in answer. If anyone wants to see the not-working original, they can look in the question. If there is any doubt, show the original line that needs to be altered, then show the final code in second snippet. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `SelfHandle`. That object is already in `BindingContext`.

To reference its fields in `CollectionViewItem.xaml.cs`, cast it to the actual type:

```cs
var itemModel = (CollectionViewItemModel)BindingContext;
Button1Command(itemModel);
```

Adapt as needed.

Comment: the main purpose is to separate method and UI, I can collect object in UI(CollectionViewItem.cs)，But I don't know how to call the method in MainPageVM？

Comment: Call the method from where? Sounds like there is some relevant code that is not shown in question. Where is the line of code that calls it? Add that code to question (or if already there, tell me where) Maybe use Messenger Publish/Subscribe. That makes it possible for code one place (in the publisher), to trigger code elsewhere (in the subscriber).